# Play 2.1 Error: Cannot find symbol bug

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.1

I have the following in my controller,

```
public static Result index() {
    return ok(indexpage.render());
}
```

my indexpage.scala.html page,

```
@main("Test") {

}
```

yet Play 2.1 is giving me the following error: error: cannot find symbol

[image: Screenshot of error]

Any ideas?

EDIT: I created another view + method in my controller, had the same exact error.

Comment: So where is `indexpage` declared? Does Play implicitly create that for you because you've got an `index.scala.html` file?

Comment: Yes, Play looks at the html files under the views folder so when I reference indexpage it refers to that view. This normally works fine which is why I'm confused.

Comment: Did you import `views.html.whatever._`? The problem seems to be in following: 1. You forgot the import. 2. The `indexpage` does not exist. 3. Some strange Play issue, so you can try `play clean`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the problem, when I cleaned up my imports I accidentally removed

```
import views.html.*;
```

from my controller class. Would have posted answer earlier but for some reason people with less than 10 reputation have to wait 8 hours before answering a question they made.

Comment: Great! You could've avoided the whole html's imput by just referring to your specific page, like `return ok(views.html.indexpage.render());` :-)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, once I cleaned my project it worked again

```
activator clean
activator run
```